# Dojo charting. The xAxis label doesn't appear the way i want

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, line, dojox.charting

I'm making an application, where i have to get some data in a Dojo chart from server and i am new with Dojo. I have a problem with the xAxis part... i need to get my values, but i always get the default one like (0,1,2,3, etc...). With yAxis, everything is ok.
Can someone helps me with that? Thanks!
 This is my code here:

```
 <div id="chartNode" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 require([
    //Require the basic chart class
    "dojox/charting/Chart",
    //Require the theme of our choosing
    "dojox/charting/themes/Tom",
    //Charting plugins:

    //We want to plot Lines    
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
    //We want to use Markers
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",

    //We'll use default x/y axes
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
    //Wait until the DOM is ready
    "dojo/domReady!"
 ], function(Chart, theme) {
//Create the chart within it's "holding" node
    var chart = new Chart("chartNode");
    //Set the theme
    chart.setTheme(theme);
//Add the only/default plot  
    chart.addPlot("default", {
        type: "Lines",
        markers: true
    });

//This is my yAxis
 var chartData = [
                     <c:forEach var="lineData" items="${data}">
                         <c:out value="${lineData.value[1]}"/>,
                     </c:forEach>
                 ];
 var xAxis = [
                 <c:forEach var="lineData" items="${data}" >
                 <c:out value="${lineData.value[0]}"/>,
             </c:forEach>
         ];
//Add axes
    chart.addAxis("x", {horizontal: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", labels: xAxis });

    chart.addAxis("y", { vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", labels: chartData });

    //Add the series of data
    chart.addSeries("DataFromXML", chartData);
 chart.render();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the chartData and xAxis end up being set too?

Comment: The chartData is the yAxis and values from it are float values like (0, 0.2, 0.56, 0 etc...) and values from xAxis are repeatable like (0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 etc...)

Comment: The problem is that the xAxis values from the chart, when i start the chart, are always the default one (1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc...), but i need them to be the repeatable one from my file... (0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2).